# append input array not get value in codeigniter controlder

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

This is my code for append input array (it is work good no error)

```js
    var max_fields      = 50;
    var wrapper         = $(".bankcostaddsize");
    var add_button      = $(".bankcost_addsize_field");
  
    var x = 1;

    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
 
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(' <div class="form-group clearfix"> <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label> <div class="col-xs-5"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-5"> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="bank_fees[]" placeholder="Fees Name" /> </div> <div class="col-md-5"> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="bank_price[]" placeholder="Price (nn.nn)" /> </div> <div class="col-md-2"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default deletebankcost">-</button> </div> </div> </div> </div> '); //add input box
        } 
        else
  {
   alert('You Reached the limits');
  }
    });
  
    $(wrapper).on("click",".deletebankcost", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove(); 
        x--;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row bankcostaddsize">       
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
      <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Fees and Costs</label>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="bank_fees[]" placeholder="Fees Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""  name="bank_price[]" placeholder="Price (nn.nn)" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default bankcost_addsize_field">+</i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now my issue is when i'm submit form it will give **only default value**, not append value in codeigniter controller. it is not give **new append data** in controller.

view file ::

```
<?php 
foreach ($feesandcode as $vlas)
{
?>
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="bank_fees[]" placeholder="Fees Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""  name="bank_price[]" placeholder="Price (nn.nn)" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default bankcost_addsize_field">+</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
} // end for loop
?>
```

controller

```
print_r($this->input->post('bank_fees'));
print_r($this->input->post('bank_price'));
```

**any help or suggestion will be helpful**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 8 for Headache and 10 coffee i find solution, in my html `<div>` is not in sequence

Example for

```
<div class="row">
  <form>
    <div class="form">
    </form> <!-- end form tag --> 
    </div> <!-- end div form class --> 
</div>
```

i don't know why this happen but is solution for me. if any one know pls give me answer for it.(sequence is matter in form tag?)